# could not find driver QueryException

Tags: fedora, mysql, php, webserver

Had this problem where my website couldn't load, and it was throwing an error:

```
could not find driver QueryException
```

Most answers hinted at uncommenting the `;extension=pdo_mysql.so` line in the `php.ini` file.

I'm using Fedora 37, and my `php.ini` file located in `/etc` had no such line. More so, all the lines having `extension` were uncommented.

Answer (score 0):

I however solved this by running `sudo dnf install php-mysqli`